# PHP identifying the URL and displaying page

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently, a user's timeline can be accessed on my site using `localhost/dateapp/timeline?profile=user1571502747`. Here user can later manually change their username from `user1571502747` to anything they like for easy access. Now what I want is if someone opens `localhost/dateapp/user1571502747` (or `mysite.com/user1571502747` when live), it automatically redirects and opens the timeline of user `user1571502747` or say it redirects to `localhost/dateapp/timeline?profile=user1571502747`. But I am not being able to figure out a way to do so. Currently, when trying to access that displays no page with page not found browser error. Of course I have haven't put anything for it yet so its natural to get this error. Can anybody guide me on doing this? Facebook does this, for reference. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: If anything needs to be done in .htaccess file then my current .htaccess has the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess for this.
Try adding this to your .htaccess file in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /timeline?profile=$1 [L]
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I have placed my .htaccess code. Please update your answer accordingly. Thank you :)

Comment: Added this rule on the last line but it didn't work.. Please check.

Comment: You tried replacing your 2nd and 3rd line with my 2nd?

Comment: No, I just placed your line at the end. Because I need those lines which are already there. I also tried to put your line before my last line but then both of them stopped working.